# Display an array of data from function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

My goal is to display a cross or a check according to the `vote.result` data from the polls.

I had to use Angular only few times and I feel pretty lost honestly.

TS file (angular) **:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-deck-card',
  templateUrl: './deck-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deck-card.component.scss'],
})
export class DeckCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() isAnim: boolean;
  @Input() inGame: boolean;
  @Input() editMode: boolean;
  @Input() readOnly: boolean;
  @Input() deckIsBase: boolean;
  @Input() card: CardDto;
  @Input() polls: PollDto[];
  @Input() isSearch: boolean;
  @Input() isImport: boolean;
  @Input() idDeck: number;
  @Input() editRight: boolean;
  @Output() changeVote = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output() deleteEvent = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Output() duplicateEvent = new EventEmitter<CardDto>();
  @Output() importEvent = new EventEmitter<CardDto>();
  @Output() sharedToCommunityEvent = new EventEmitter<CardDto>();
  safeIcon: SafeUrl | string;
  votes: VoteDto[];

  constructor(private readonly authState: AuthState,
              private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.safeIcon = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.card?.theme?.icon);
    this.votes = this.polls?.find(p => p.card.id === this.card?.id)?.votes;
  }

  /**
   * Emit the card ID to delete the card
   * @return void
   */
  deleteCard(): void {
    this.deleteEvent.emit(this.card.id);
  }

  showTheResult(): string {
    console.log(this.polls);
    console.log(this.votes);
    this.polls?.forEach(vote => {
      if (vote.voted && vote.result == false) {
        // display a mat-icon cross
        console.log(vote)
        return '<mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>'
      } else if (vote.voted && vote.result == true) {
        // display a mat-icon check
        console.log(vote)
        return '<mat-icon>done</mat-icon>'
      }
    });
    return '';
  }
}
```

My 2 `console.log` in `showTheResult()` are always undefined.
So, obviously, the console log in the if condition are never reached.

HTML file **:**

```
  <div class="card-body" [class.card-body-readOnly]="readOnly">
    <p class="main-text" [class.readOnly]="readOnly" [class.short]="inGame && isAnim"
       [class.long]="!editMode && !isAnim">{{card?.text}}</p>
    <p>{{showTheResult()}}</p>
    <p>DISPLAY HERE THE MAT-ICON</p>
    <span *ngIf="isAnim || editMode" class="sub-text">#{{card?.id}}</span>
  </div>
```

can someone show me the way ?

The DTOs look like this:

```
export interface PollDto {
  id: number;
  result: boolean;
  voted: boolean;
  priority: number;
  card: CardDto;
  votes: VoteDto[];
}

export interface VoteDto {
  participantId: number;
  participantName?: string;
  pollId: number;
  result: boolean;
}
```

Comment: One observation : `{{showheResult()}}` should be `{{showTheResult()}}` . Also, Can you please share your JSON for `this.polls` & `this.votes` in `showTheResult()` method.

Comment: export interface PollDto {
  id: number;
  result: boolean;
  voted: boolean;
  priority: number;
  card: CardDto;
  votes: VoteDto[];
}

export interface VoteDto {
  participantId: number;
  participantName?: string;
  pollId: number;
  result: boolean;
}

Is it what u need ?

Comment: You added interfaces but what i am looking for the response object. I just want to see are you getting `this.polls` & `this.votes` in `showTheResult()` method or not.

Answer (score 0):

since your this.polls is an @Input(), you don't know if this variable is actually loaded when you reach ngOnInit lifecycle.

When working with @Input data, if you want to catch the moment data is loaded, you should watch the changes :

https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/detect-input-property-changes-ngonchanges-setters

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
  }
```

This way, you will see if ever your data are loaded, if not, that means the problem is in the parent container component.

> Also, a quick note : I don't think you should return HTML in your
> method, you probably want to handle this another way, with a directive
> or something, this would not be a good practice.

Cheers ! :)

Comment: i just follow the link and your comment with `ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges) {
   console.log(changes.polls.currentValue);
   console.log(changes.votes.currentValue);
  }
`
I tried with `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` or `Default`

But can not read currentValue of Undefined, so the mistake is in parent component in your opinion ?

Comment: Yes, I would deactivate this component and focus on the parent to figure this out.

Comment: `<app-deck-card [isAnim]="isAnim" [card]="card"  [polls]="themeElement.polls" *ngFor="let card of themeElement.cards" (changeVote)="changePollVote($event)"></app-deck-card>`
used in ThemeListComponent, already use this Input... 
`export class ThemeListComponent {
  @Input() themeList = [];
  @Input() polls: PollDto[];
  changePollVote(cardId: number): void {
    if (this.isAnim) {
      const poll: PollDto = this.polls.find(p => p.card.id === cardId);
      this.store.dispatch(new SocketAction.Send.Poll.Submit(this.cardiagState.gameId, poll.id, !poll.result));}}`
And here it's works

Comment: So you solved it ?

Comment: Nah i dont, i just wrote that the parent component already use an @Input() polls: PollDto[] and in this parent, everything works, but in my child Polls is never defined

Comment: Obviously there is some code missing here, I don't see the "themeElement" attribute in the ThemeListComponent. Could you update the original post with the whole code of this parent component ?

Comment: Ok, i just succeed to transfer data through my child, but my Object polls has 22 poll, and now with the `this.polls.forEach`, the iteraion is made 22 times for each poll (22x22). I just want to iterate one time on each poll, dunno why this part of code act like this?

Comment: Are you sure this is not because of this loop : *ngFor="let card of themeElement.cards" ?